# Detect specific angle in image with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm currently developing an application that takes images and detect a specific angle in that image.
The images always look something like this: [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WRQ6.jpg).

I want to detect the angle of the bottom cone.

In order to do that i crop that image in image and use two Houghline algorithms. One for the cone and one for the table at the bottom. This works failry well and i get the correct result in 90% of the images.

[result of the two algorithms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsUPy.jpg)

1. [Doesnt work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPgSh.jpg)
2. [Doesnt work either](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNR11.jpg)

My approach works for now because i can guarantee that the cone will alwys be in an angle range of 5 to 90°. So i can filter the houghlines based on their angle.

However i wonder if their is a better approach to this. This is my first time working with OpenCV, so maybe this community has some tips to improve the whole thing. Any help is appreciated!

My code for the cone so far:

```
 public  (Bitmap bmp , double angle) Calculate(Mat imgOriginal, Mat imgCropped, int Y)
    {
        Logging.Log("Functioncall: Calculate");
        var finalAngle = 0.0;

        Mat imgWithLines = imgOriginal.Clone();
       how croppedImage look's

        var grey = new Mat();
        CvInvoke.CvtColor(imgCropped, grey, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);

        var bilateral = new Mat();
        
        CvInvoke.BilateralFilter(grey, bilateral, 15, 85, 15);

        var blur = new Mat();
        CvInvoke.GaussianBlur(bilateral, blur, new Size(5, 5), 0); // Kernel reduced from 31 to 5

        var edged = new Mat();
        CvInvoke.Canny(blur, edged, 0, 50);

        var iterator = true;
        var counter = 0;
        var hlThreshhold = 28;
        while (iterator &&counter<40)
        {
            counter++;
            var threshold = hlThreshhold;
            var rho = 1;
            var theta =  Math.PI / 180;
            var lines = new VectorOfPointF();
            
            CvInvoke.HoughLines(edged, lines, rho, theta, threshold);

            var angles = CalculateAngles(lines);
            if (angles.Length > 1)
            {
                hlThreshhold += 1;

            }

            if (angles.Length < 1)
            {
                hlThreshhold -= 1;

            }

            if (angles.Length == 1)
            {
                
                try
                {
                    //Calc the more detailed position of glassLine and use it for Calc with ConeLine instead of perfect horizontal line
                    var glassLines = new VectorOfPointF();
                    var glassTheta = Math.PI / 720; // accuracy:  PI / 180 => 1 degree | PI / 720 => 0.25 degree | 
                    CvInvoke.HoughLines(edged, glassLines, rho, glassTheta, threshold);
                    var glassEdge = CalculateGlassEdge(glassLines);
                    iterator = false;
                    // finalAngle = angles.FoundAngle; // Anzeige der Winkel auf 2 Nachkommastellen
                    CvInvoke.Line(imgWithLines, new Point((int)angles.LineCoordinates[0].P1.X, (int)angles.LineCoordinates[0].P1.Y + Y), new Point((int)angles.LineCoordinates[0].P2.X, (int)angles.LineCoordinates[0].P2.Y + Y), new MCvScalar(0, 0, 255), 5);
                    CvInvoke.Line(imgWithLines, new Point((int)glassEdge.LineCoordinates[0].P1.X, (int)glassEdge.LineCoordinates[0].P1.Y + Y), new Point((int)glassEdge.LineCoordinates[0].P2.X, (int)glassEdge.LineCoordinates[0].P2.Y + Y), new MCvScalar(255, 255, 0), 5);
                    // calc Angle ConeLine and GlassLine
                    finalAngle = 90 + angles.LineCoordinates[0].GetExteriorAngleDegree(glassEdge.LineCoordinates[0]);
                    
                  
                    finalAngle = Math.Round(finalAngle, 1);
                    //Calc CrossPoint 
                    PointF crossPoint = getCrossPoint(angles.LineCoordinates[0], glassEdge.LineCoordinates[0]);
                    //Draw dashed Line through crossPoint
                    drawDrashedLineInCrossPoint(imgWithLines, crossPoint, 30);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    finalAngle = 0.0;
                    imgWithLines = imgOriginal.Clone();
                }

            }

        }
```

Image cropping (the table is always on the same position, so i use this position and a height parameter to only get the bottom of the cone )

```
 public Mat ReturnCropped(Bitmap imgOriginal, int GlassDiscLine, int HeightOffset)
    {
       var rect = new Rectangle(0, 2500-GlassDiscLine-HeightOffset, imgOriginal.Width, 400);
        return  new Mat(imgOriginal.ToMat(), rect);
      
    }
```

Comment: can you show image where it does not work? Can you show how you crop the images?

Comment: @Micka Added the crop functions to my question. At the moment i can't provide a image where it does not work. I'll provide it as soon as i can!

Comment: Hard to answer with just one sample.

Comment: I've added two pictures where it doenst work

Comment: How exact do you need this angle to be ? A different approach might be cropping the image for only the lower 2/3rds of the cone, then ````findContouts()```` and look at the main axis via ````fitLine()````. More robust, less accurate. Or use this to get a starting angle for further processing: Finde the lower intersection between main axis line and contours, take it from there.